# get max value of column using jpa criteria query

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I want to get the maximum value of column `relationId` from table `ElementRelationType`
I have written code but its giving error

```
CriteriaBuilder cb1 = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ElementRelationTypes> cq1 = cb1.createQuery(ElementRelationTypes.class);
Root<ElementRelationTypes> root = cq1.from(ElementRelationTypes.class);
cq1.select(cb1.max(root.get("relationId")));
```

select and max both giving error
how to get the integer max value

```
public class ElementRelationTypes {

private RelationId relationLangPK=new RelationId(); 

private Country country;
private Status status;


@EmbeddedId
public RelationId getRelationLangPK() {
    return relationLangPK;
}
public void setRelationLangPK(RelationId relationLangPK) {
    this.relationLangPK = relationLangPK;
}

@Transient
public Integer getRelationId() {
    return getRelationLangPK().getRelationId();
}
public void setRelationId(Integer relationId) {
    getRelationLangPK().setRelationId(relationId);
}
@Transient
public Language getLanguage() {
    return getRelationLangPK().getLanguage();
}
public void setLanguageCode(Language language) {
    getRelationLangPK().setLanguage(language);
}
```

and

```
public class RelationId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer relationId;
private Language language;

@JoinColumn(name=PersistenseConstants.ELEMENT_RELATION_TYPE_COL_RELATION_ID)
public Integer getRelationId() {
    return relationId;
}

public void setRelationId(Integer relationId) {
    this.relationId = relationId;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name=PersistenseConstants.LANGUAGE_ENTITY_COL_LANG_CODE)
public Language getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(Language language) {
    this.language = language;
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't post which errors do you receive, so I have to guess.

[CriteriaBuilder.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#max(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) accepts `Expression<N>` where `N extends Number`

At the same time [Root.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get(java.lang.String)) by default returns `Path<Object>` which is inconvertible to `Expression<Number>`.

So to make your call to `max` work you need to specify generic parameter to `root.get`:

```
cq1.select(cb1.max(root.<Number>get("relationId")));
```

here you can replace `Number` with an actual type of `relationId` (`Long`, `BigInteger` etc.)

**UPDATE:** @perissf [addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022623/get-max-value-of-column-using-jpa-criteria-query#451518) another issue with your code. If you are going to select maximal value (which is numeric) you should declare your `CriteriaQuery` as a query to `Number` not `ElementRelationTypes`

Comment: Its working for non composit key,but in my case relationId is composit key.I have provided my class info

Comment: @perissf I'm sorry, I just tried to mention that your answer highlights *another* useful point. I'm not sure how it is better, but it is certainly different. Address OP if you think that your answer deserves to be accepted. I already voted up your answer anyway.

Comment: No problem. Just deleted my answer when new information arrived!

Comment: @Surya It isn't clear what's the root cause of the error here. Maybe you should consider to post another question. Don't forget to include what exactly doesn't work, compiler errors (if any), exception messages and stacktraces (if any)

Comment: @perissf Why? Your answer was absolutely relevant to original question.

Comment: Because I was assuming that `relationId` was a Numeric type. It's not the case, although you are right in saying that it was not possible to have this information at the time of answering.

Comment: @perissf Not sure: `public Integer getRelationId()`. I believe it's still Numeric